# Consider the equation $2R*x^2 - (2R\cos\frac{B-C}{2})*x+r=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, polynomials

$2R*x^2 -  (2R\cos\frac{B-C}{2})*x+r=0$

We have the triangle ABC

Where $r = 4R\sin\frac{A}{2}\sin\frac{B}{2}\sin\frac{C}{2}$

R is the circumradius of the triangle ABC.

I have the following answer options:

1. $cos^2\frac{B-C}{2}<\frac{2r}{R}$
2. $2r > R$
3. $\sin\frac{A}{2}$ Is a root
4. The equation has no real roots.

I honestly don't even know how to start here, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a simple way to get some progress.

If (2) is true, then $\frac{2r}{R}>1$ and that would imply that (1) is true. Thus, proving (2) is false proves that both (1) and (2) are false.

If you take a look at Euler's theorem in geometry (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem_in_geometry), it shows that $R>2r$ proving (2) is false. This knocks out two answer choices.

Then, if you look at the discriminant, using that same property of $R>2r$, you can find a real solution by making $\cos(\frac{B-C}{2})$ equal 1. Since a real solution is possible that rules out (4).